# .NET Core OData: override the entity set routing convention for navigation key

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

In non-Core project with `Microsoft.AspNet.OData package`, it was possible to override

`SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext context, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)`

from `EntitySetRoutingConvention` like below to enable correct routing for `"~/entityset/key/navigation/key"` endpoint.

In Core (.NET 6-8) it all looks completely different.

Is there a way to achieve the same result with .NET Core and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` package?

```
public class NavigationKeyRoutingConvention : EntitySetRoutingConvention
{
    public override string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext context, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get && odataPath.PathTemplate == "~/entityset/key/navigation/key")
        {
            var navigationSegment = odataPath.Segments[2] as Microsoft.OData.UriParser.NavigationPropertySegment;
            var navigationProperty = navigationSegment.NavigationProperty;

            string actionName = "Get" + navigationProperty.Name;
            if (actionMap.Contains(actionName))
            {
                var keySegment = odataPath.Segments[1] as Microsoft.OData.UriParser.KeySegment;
                context.RouteData.Values[ODataRouteConstants.Key] = keySegment.Keys.FirstOrDefault().Value;

                var relatedKeySegment = odataPath.Segments[3] as Microsoft.OData.UriParser.KeySegment;
                context.RouteData.Values[ODataRouteConstants.RelatedKey] = relatedKeySegment.Keys.FirstOrDefault().Value;

                return actionName;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
// Create the default collection of built-in conventions.
var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
// Insert the custom convention at the start of the collection.
conventions.Insert(0, new NavigationKeyRoutingConvention());

config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEDMModel(), new DefaultODataPathHandler(), conventions);
```